# BotFramework sorry the service was upgraded and we need to start over

Tags: bots, botframework

I have a bot with 340 users currently and some of them are using an older version. Recently I updated the version on my side and sent a message to the users and when they tried to reply, they got a message saying "Sorry the service was upgraded and we need to start over"

[image]

I understand this has to do with the upgradeDialogId. I already have it and I am not sure why it doesn't get triggered.

```
const
    connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
        appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
        appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD,
        gzipData: true
    })

const
    bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector)
        .set('autoBatchDelay', 0)
        .set('dialogErrorMessage', common.error().text)
bot.use(builder.Middleware.dialogVersion({
    version: VERSION,
    resetCommand: /^reset/i
}))

bot.use(builder.Middleware.firstRun({
    version: VERSION,
    dialogId: '/firstRun',
    upgradeDialogId: '/upgrade'
}))
bot.dialog('/upgrade', upgrade)
function upgrade(session, args) {
    session.endDialog("We just upgraded to a better version")
}
```

Am I missing something with respect to the upgrade dialog logic?

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found this code snippet in the Middleware.ts file

```
static firstRun(options: IFirstRunOptions): IMiddlewareMap {
        return {
            botbuilder: (session, next) => {
                if (session.sessionState.callstack.length == 0) {
                    // New conversation so check first run version
                    var cur = session.userData[consts.Data.FirstRunVersion] || 0.0;
                    var curMajor = Math.floor(cur);
                    var major = Math.floor(options.version);
                    if (major > curMajor) {
                        // Run user through full first run experience
                        session.beginDialog(consts.DialogId.FirstRun, <IFirstRunDialogArgs>{
                            version: options.version,
                            dialogId: options.dialogId,
                            dialogArgs: options.dialogArgs
                        });
                    } else if (options.version > cur && options.upgradeDialogId) {
                        // Run user through upgrade experience
                        session.beginDialog(consts.DialogId.FirstRun, <IFirstRunDialogArgs>{
                            version: options.version,
                            dialogId: options.upgradeDialogId,
                            dialogArgs: options.upgradeDialogArgs
                        });
                    } else {
                        next();
                    }
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice the else if part where firstRun dialog is being called. I think there is a bug here in the code and upgradeDialogId should be called instead. Anyone who can confirm this?